# Bootstrap reorder col-xs-12

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap and would like to have my columns reorder only in xs view.

For example:

large screens - tablet this is what it looks like:

column A ------- column B

The problem I am facing is when i get to xs it looks like this:

- column A
- column B

When I want it to look like this:

- column B
- column A

Comment: Provide us with some details - code, relevant things to the question and what you've tried in terms of debugging.

Comment: Not sure with plain `CSS`, but yea you can take help of `jquery` if you'd like to..

Comment: If they are static columns, then an easy solution would be to have two column B's. One on top of column A, give it visible-xs, and the other below column A, give it hidden-xs. But, this is amateurish I guess, but simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with Bootstrap [Column Reordering](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Working Example;

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        B
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        A
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Just need reverse the floats on the columns. have a look at below snippets.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zab92q8v/show/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    Column B
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     Column A
  </div>
</div>
```